# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить нужные данные из многомерного массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить нужные данные из многомерного массива PHP.
Имеется массив:

```
Array ( 
        [status] => finish 
        [data] => Array 
        ( 
            [frequency] => 332 
            [count_keys] => 10 
            [array] => Array 
            (
                [grundfos alpha2 25 40 180] => 332 
                [насос grundfos alpha2 25 40 180] => 153 
                [grundfos alpha2 l 25 40 180] => 129 
                [grundfos alpha2 25 40 180 цена] => 67 
                [насос grundfos alpha2 l 25 40 180] => 60 
                [grundfos alpha2 25 40 180 инструкция] => 58 
                [grundfos alpha2 l 25 40 180 инструкция] => 32 
                [grundfos alpha2 25 40 180 купить] => 17 
                [grundfos alpha2 l 25 40 180 цена] => 11 
                [grundfos alpha2 l 25 40 180 характеристики] => 8 
            ) 
        )
```

Мне нужно получить значения, можно в отдельный массив:

```
[grundfos alpha2 25 40 180] => 332 
[насос grundfos alpha2 25 40 180] => 153
...
```

Comment: $newArray = $array['data']['array'] - будет содержать то что вы написали

Comment: @EatMyDust, спасибо большое, разобрался!